# Preview text on only one li having same class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, summernote

I have a `<ul>` in which when I type on a input box the text is previewed on the list. I also have a button in which I can add more `<li>`s to the `<ul>`. I want to have it so that when I type in a text box the text is previewed on that one `<li>`.

My code:

```
<ul class="nav nav-list nav-stacked" id="courseNav">
    <li class="title">
        <a href="#">Overview</a>
    </li>
    <li class="topics" style="margin-top: -12px">
        <a href="#">Topic</a>
    </li>
    <li class="topics">
        <a href="#">Topic</a>
    </li>
    <li class="topics">
        <a href="#">Topic</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

My button code:

```
$('#addCourse').click(function() {
    // adds a li to the courseNav
    $('#courseNav').append('<li class="newTopic" id="newLi"><a href="#">Topic</a></li>');

    $('.newTopic').click(function() {
        $('#courseDiv').css('display', 'none');
        $('#topicDiv').css('display', 'block');
    }); 
});

$('#delCourse').click(function() {
    $('#newLi').remove();
});
```

My preview code:

```
var input = $('#editorText'),
    preview = $('.topics a');

    input.keyup(function (e) {
        preview.html(input.val());
        preview.css('padding-top', '10px');
        preview.css('padding-bottom', '10px');
        preview.css('padding-right', '15px');
        preview.css('padding-left', '15px');
        preview.css('word-wrap', 'break-word');
    });
```

The problem is that the text is previewed on all the `<li>`s with `class` "topic". How can I fix this? I can assign `id`s to the `<li>`s but then what about the ones added by the button?

[New fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gxwcqqfx)

Comment: Fix your fiddle please, it doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check it out [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gxwcqqfx/4/). On click you can save current node, and also `keyup` binding must be out of `click` handler

```
input.keyup(function (e){
   ...    
}

$('.topics').click(function(){
    preview = $(this).find('a');
    ...
}
```

Comment: thanks but what if I want the input box for the topic title to be different for every li as well. Again thanks for your help!!

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you want something like this http://jsfiddle.net/gxwcqqfx/5/, to achieve that you can on every click get value from `li` and set to `input`

Comment: That is exactly what I want. One more thing. I have a button which adds lis to my nav-list. Will this method work for that as well?

Comment: Yes, it will. Just use [delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) `$(document).on('click', '.topics',function(){}` instead of `$('.topics').click(function(){}` http://jsfiddle.net/gxwcqqfx/6/

Comment: Alright.. One last thing. When I click on my li why does the text "topic" appear on my text box and how can I remove it?

Comment: I guess "Topic" it's a name of `li` which you will be edit, but if you want "Topic" can be excluded http://jsfiddle.net/gxwcqqfx/9/